# redirect to action using jquery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, post, redirect, razor

im using MVC3. im trying to redirectToAction after doing a jquery post.

edit: sorry for not  being specific. Whenever it reaches the return RedirectToAction, it just refreshes the same page and returns to the same current view.

my View code is as follows:

```
 $("button[name='command']").click(function () {

        var checked_status = null;
        if ($("#select_all").is(':checked')) {
            checked_status = true;
        } else {
            checked_status = false;
        }

        $.post('@Url.Action("SaveInvitations", "Contractors")',
              {
                  command: $(this).val(),
                  selectedContractors: $("input[name='selectedContractors']:checked").map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get().join(","),
                  page: $(".selected").text(),
                  CheckedAll: checked_status
              });
    });
```

and my controller has the following:

```
        if (command == "skip")
        {
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("No contractors where selected");
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
...
TempData["message"] = string.Format("The invitations have been send successfully.");
                Session["subModel"] = null;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Then again, im just trying to do a redirectToAction after a jquery $.post. What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: Could you be more specific than "doesn't work"? What happens, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RedirectToAction is a server side method. Since you are doing a jQuery post, you probably need to do that once your post is completed.

```
 $.post('@Url.Action("SaveInvitations", "Contractors")',
              {
                  command: $(this).val(),
                  selectedContractors: $("input[name='selectedContractors']:checked").map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get().join(","),
                  page: $(".selected").text(),
                  CheckedAll: checked_status
              },function(){
  window.location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
});
```

Here is another way to do write the above method, using the explicit call to `done` to make it more readable.

```
 var url='@Url.Action("SaveInvitations", "Contractors")';
 var data =  {
                  command: $(this).val(),
                  selectedContractors: $("input[name='selectedContractors']:checked")
                          .map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get().join(","),
                  page: $(".selected").text(),
                  CheckedAll: checked_status
             };
 $.post(url,data)
  .done(function(){
        window.location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
   });
```

If you are doing a redirect after the jQuery ajax operation, Why not directly call the Action method (normal form posting) and then do redirect from there ? People usually use jQuery ajax operations to have partial page updates. are you sure you want to do like this ?

Comment: Yes, I know it would be easier to do a normal posting, but I dont know how to catch the parameters im sending in the action, so its a lot easier if I catch them in the js and then do a Post, or at least, its faster for me right now. I could do a refactor later once I know how to catch them in the action.

Comment: Use strongly typed views and post it to your action. That is much better than this approach . What if someone accessing your site with a browser where javascript is disabled ?

Comment: Well, I had some problems with that at first, because the page is very complex, but I'll do a refactoring and try to catch them in a view model object.